# Afectar a varios DOM con una misma funcion con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Necesito que la función hola() declarada en el archivo js afecte a ambos DOM, sin importar en que archivo, si A.hmtl o B.html, este el trigger de la función que en este caso se encuentra en el botón del archivo A.

Lo que busco hacer es una especie de currículo web, este estará hecho del clásico html, css y js (osea que correrá en los navegadores), sin embargo, este currículo no estará alojado en un servidor, ni va estar en Internet, ni nada por el estilo. Solo sera un compendio de archivos (no tan largos), bien organizados que al enviarselo a alguien, que sepa o no de programacion, lo unico que tendria que hacer es darle click a un archivo index y ya, podria verlos y moverse por donde quiera del mismo.

No se guardara nada, ni espero un feedback en cuanto a las cosas que la persona realice en ese currículo. Porque busco como hacer esto? Porque no quiero un html de 1.000.000 de lineas de código, por lo cual, quiero dividir las sub vistas que se desplegaran dependiendo de lo que se quiera ver (como angular hace). ya se como dividir las vistas ahora mi problemas es este, como altero las inclusiones que vienen desde otros archivos con js si el trigger que acciona la funcion esta en el archivo padre a donde todos llegaran.

**Archivo A.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id='aqui'>
<head>
    <title>hola</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <object id="hola-mundo" data="vista-1.html"></object>
    </div>
    <button onclick="hola()">
        <p>Cambiar</p>
    </button>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="hola.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Archivo B.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="alla">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="vista-1">
        <p>hola mundo</p>
    </div>
    <button id="btn-2">
        <p>hola</p>
    </button>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="hola.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Archivo hola.js**

```js
$('#btn-2').click(function(){
    $('p').css('color','blue')
})

function hola(){
    $('#aqui p').css('color','pink')
    $('#vista-1 p').css('color','pink')
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la verdadera razon detras de esto? ¿Necesitas actualizar la pagina B al presionar algo en la pagina A? Te lo pregunto, porque lo que estas planteando es imposible. Si ese fuera el caso, te lo estas planteando mal. Creo que algo como Meteor podría ayudarte, pero no soy experto en el tema.

Comment: Y cuál es el problema en sí?

Comment: He removido Stack Snippet porque este sólo debe usarse en código HTML/CSS/JavaScript que sea ejecutable en la página. En el caso de esta pregunta se está llamando a archivos por medio de rutas relativas pero estas no funcionan en Stack Snippet.

Comment: ¿Las páginas están abiertas en la misma computadora?¿O es en computadoras diferentes?

Comment: Es mas si intenta el codigo que puse arriba, la funcion hola() le cambia el color al "p" del archivo A pero no llega a "p" del archivo B... ese es mi problema y llevo tiempo tratando de resolverlo.

Comment: Te estaba escribiendo una respuesta para tu pregunta... pero viendo tus comentarios, parece que lo que buscas no es ni parecido a lo que te estaba escribiendo. Deberías darle al botón de [edit] y añadir esa información y, si es posible, una mejor descripción del sistema y de cómo esperarías que funcione

Comment: Si lo acabo de agregar, soy nuevo en esto de preguntar por stack, disculpen.

Comment: Haciendo click en el botón 2, te cambia el color de los dos p verdad?

Comment: No haciendo click al boton 2 (que se encuentra en el archivo B) solo cambio el color del p o de los p, si hubieran mas ,del archivo B.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es enviar tu CV en HTML, te recomendaría dos cosas: 1) no lo rompas en múltiples ficheros, hazlo todo en uno grande (aunque sea de un millón de líneas y mezclando HTML/JS/CSS, no importará si está bien organizado y puedes añadir algún comentario por si miran la consola); y 2) No uses jQuery, o mejor dicho: no dependas de nada externo (esta recomendación incluye a la primera). Si la persona que ve tu CV en HTML no está conectado a Internet o pierde un archivo, tu CV dejará de funcionar y quedará mal. Creo que para lo que buscas sería mejor un único archivo auto-contenido.

Comment: Yo llegue a pensar lo mismo y lo mas probable es que termine haciéndolo de esa forma como dices tu, pero en este punto creo que quiero la respuesta de este problema, solo porque llevo días tratando de hacerlo y no he podido. No me gustaría quedarme en un "no pude hacerlo". Ojo en este punto no se si lo que quiero hacer, realmente es posible, con la tecnología actual.

Comment: Por eso te decía que hacía falta más información. Te estaba escribiendo una respuesta, pero no funcionaría con el protocolo `file:///` que es como el usuario vería tus ficheros. Podría haber otras opciones, pero haría falta saber cómo están relacionados los archivos A y B: ¿uno abre al otro? ¿o se incluye de alguna forma (mediante objetos o via AJAX)? ¿están los dos abiertos al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Imaginemos que el currículo tiene un aside donde habrán varios secciones tipo "datos personales", "formación académica", etc. Al darle click a algunos de estos, en el archivo A o index.html (que seria el archivo padre) habra un div que contendrá al tag object, lo único que tendría que hacer para cambiar de vista interna, seria capturar el url de la sección del aside clickeada y remplazarle el value del attr 'data' al object y el contenido interno cambiaría.

Answer (score 1):

Usando clases (ej: .soy-una-clase) y con jQuery puedes cambiarles a todos los elementos con esa clase, el estilo que vos quieras.

```js
$('.button-changer').click(function(){
    $('.colorChange').css('color','blue');
})
```

```css
.colorChange {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="colorChange">Hello!</p>
<p class="colorChange">Hello!</p>
<button class="button-changer">Click me!</button>
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/bitxelus/pen/PKYwXy

Comment: Esto sólo afectaría a los elementos de la misma página, pero no a elementos de otra página diferente (sería un mismo DOM y no varios DOM diferentes como se espefica en la pregunta).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es una función y llamarlo a través del atributos onclick de HTML. Todo aquellos elementos de html que lo invoquen podrán acceder a el. Por ejemplo:

```js
//tu archivo js 
function hacerAlgo(event){
  // Agregar aqúi lo que quieres hacer
  //con event.target tienes acceso al elemento que invocó la función y jugar con el
  alert(event.target.innerText)
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Página 1</h2>
<button onclick="hacerAlgo(event)">boton 1</button>
<h2>Página 2</h2>
<button onclick="hacerAlgo(event)">boton 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```